# How to prevent jQuery apendTo from duplicating content

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to move a div(.titleContainer) inside another div(.imageContainer a) by using jQuery prependTo function, but for some reason the the content that was previously appended is also added to the element that's receiving an appended element. Thanks!

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.titleContainer').each(function(){
        $(this).prependTo('.imageContainer a');
    });
});
```

```css
.imageContainer{
    background: rgb(144, 144, 221);
}
.card{
    margin-right: 20px; 
    flex: 0 0 30%;
}
h3{
    color: black
}
body{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
    <div class="card">
        <div class="titleContainer">
            <h3>title1</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="imageContainer">
            <a href="">
                <img src="" alt="">
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="card">
        <div class="titleContainer">
            <h3>title2</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="imageContainer">
            <a href="">
                <img src="" alt="">
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="card">
        <div class="titleContainer">
            <h3>title3</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="imageContainer">
            <a href="">
                <img src="" alt="">
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
```

Comment: Make sure that for every load of the page, you should clear first the contents of the element you want to append

Comment: what are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: @NidhinJoseph I want to move the (.titleContainer) div inside the (.imageContainer a) div

Comment: You mean prependTo method not appendTo. @Charly

Answer (score 2):

You need to target `.imageContainer` within the same `.card`. Using `'.imageContainer a'` will target all `a`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.titleContainer').each(function() {
    $(this).prependTo($(this).closest('.card').find('.imageContainer a'));
  });
});
```

```css
.imageContainer {
  background: rgb(144, 144, 221);
}

.card {
  margin-right: 20px;
  flex: 0 0 30%;
}

h3 {
  color: black
}

body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="titleContainer">
      <h3>title1</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="imageContainer">
      <a href="">
        <img src="" alt="">
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="card">
    <div class="titleContainer">
      <h3>title2</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="imageContainer">
      <a href="">
        <img src="" alt="">
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="card">
    <div class="titleContainer">
      <h3>title3</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="imageContainer">
      <a href="">
        <img src="" alt="">
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$(function(){
    $('.titleContainer').each(function(){
      $(this).prependTo($(this).next().find('a'));
    });
});
```

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/kostasx/pen/GRREaVb?editors=0010)

Note: `$(function(){}) === $(document).ready(function(){});`

Comment: Thanks, but this code makes (.titleContainer) go next to the a tag and not inside like i need it to.